# Can I get wget -x to download the folder structure but not create the domain directory?

Tags: wget

I'm currently doing this:

```
wget -i download.txt -x
```

It creates a root directory `example.org/`. What I'd like to do is only create subdirectories.

Is there a way to compel wget into doing what I'd like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the man page the parameter `-nH` should do what you are looking for:

```
   Directory Options
   -nd
   --no-directories
       Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively.  With this option turned on, all
       files will get saved to the current directory, without clobbering (if a name shows up more than once,
       the filenames will get extensions .n).

   -x
   --force-directories
       The opposite of -nd---create a hierarchy of directories, even if one would not have been created
       otherwise.  E.g. wget -x http://fly.srk.fer.hr/robots.txt will save the downloaded file to
       fly.srk.fer.hr/robots.txt.

   -nH
   --no-host-directories
       Disable generation of host-prefixed directories.  By default, invoking Wget with -r
       http://fly.srk.fer.hr/ will create a structure of directories beginning with fly.srk.fer.hr/.  This
       option disables such behavior.
```

I'm not sure that you really need the `-i` param used in your example.

From my point of view, to achieve what you described is enough to run:

```
wget -xnH download.txt
```

Comment: Oh I thought I tried that but it works now. Thanks!